# How can I find the jobId that caused node failure in slurm?

Tags: hpc, slurm

I know that `sacctmgr` command can list the event history of nodes with the reason.

```
sacctmgr show event Start=09/01-00:00 format=nodename,timestart,timeend,state,reason,user
```

This command gives the following output

```
gnodeXX         2020-09-04T20:21:34 2020-09-05T01:21:38  DRAIN               Kill task failed         root(ZZ)                      
gnodeXX         2020-09-09T16:44:55 2020-09-09T17:50:21  DOWN*                 Not responding    slurm(DDDD)
```

Is there any way I can get the jobId or username that caused the Node Failure or any info on the task for which kill failed? The user column gives either of two outputs for all results root(ZZ) and slurm(DDDD) and I am not sure what these imply.

Comment: `/var/log/slumctld` on the head node should tell you.